# Django chained JOINS

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have  these models:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
  ...

class Computer(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(Person)
  ...

class Monitor(models.Model):
  computer = models.ForeignKey(Computer)
  ...
```

How do I query for the Monitors of a single Person using django ORM in a **single** SQL query?

Comment: Try: `Monitor.objects.filter(computer__in=person.computer_set.all())`

Comment: It is possible, but two SQL queries are used for that. What I want is to is to have a single SQL query with two JOINS.

Comment: did you try it? just print the queries generated. My guess is, it will  evaluate in 1 query

Comment: Why not `Monitor.objects.filter(computer__user = person)` where person is an object (i.e., the person whose list of monitors you want.

Comment: karthikr: You're right. It is one query. But not two joins. Just select wrapped into other select.

Comment: @Josh make that an answer..

Comment: Great! Happy to help. It's an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not `Monitor.objects.filter(computer__user = person)` where person is an object (i.e., the person whose list of monitors you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Monitor.objects.filter(computer__user__username=username)
```

If you do not know the username, replace with other field of the `Person` model.